# how when the login is successful the token already exists, it will move to the home page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If you successfully log in and have got the token, then the page will redirect to home and after I have successfully logged in and got the token, see the picture taken .

[image] .

the code is in the login folder, thank you for helping .

```
const FormItem = Form.Item;

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: this.props.isAuthenticated,
      errorMessage: null,
      isErorloaded: false
    };
  }

  handleRegisterGoogle = request => {
    this.props.loginWithGoogle(this.props.history, request);
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
          await this.props.loginWithForm(values);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {

    console.log(this.props.token);
    const { form } = this.props;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
    const { errorMessage, isErorloaded,isAuthenticated } = this.state;

    if (isAuthenticated === true) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
        console.log(errorMessage);
        return (
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
            <FormItem className="login-form__input-text">
              {getFieldDecorator("email", {
                rules: [
                  {
                    type: "email",
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input your email!"
                  }
                ]
              })(
                <Input
                  size={"large"}
                  prefix={
                    <Icon type={"user"} style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />
                  }
                  placeholder={"Email"}
                />
              )}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem className="login-form__input-text">
              {getFieldDecorator("password", {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input your password!"
                  }
                ]
              })(
                <Input
                  size={"large"}
                  prefix={
                    <Icon type={"lock"} style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />
                  }
                  placeholder={"Password"}
                  type="password"
                />
              )}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem className="login-form__checkBox">
              {getFieldDecorator("remember", {
                valuePropName: "checked",
                initialValue: true
              })(<Checkbox>{strings.login_remember_me}</Checkbox>)}
              <a className="login-form__forgot" href="/">
                {strings.login_forgot_password}
              </a>
              <div>
                <Button
                  size={"large"}
                  htmlType="submit"
                  className="login-form__button__submit"
                >
                  <h4>{strings.login_enter}</h4>
                </Button>
                <div className="login-form__error-box">
                  {isErorloaded ? (
                    <p className="login-form__error-notif"> {errorMessage}</p>
                  ) : null}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="login-form__separator">
                <p className="login-form__separator__text">
                  {strings.login_option}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="login-form__socmed-box">
                <ButtonFacebook
                  className="login-form__socmed-button"
                  onSubmit={this.handleRegisterGoogle}
                >
                  <p> {strings.facebook}</p>
                </ButtonFacebook>
                <ButtonGoogle
                  className="login-form__socmed-button"
                  onSubmit={this.handleRegisterGoogle}
                >
                  <p> {strings.google}</p>
                </ButtonGoogle>
              </div>
              <p style={{ marginTop: "70px" }}>
                {strings.formatString(
                  strings.login_quote,
                  <a href="/register" className="login-form__register">
                    {strings.login_register}{" "}
                  </a>
                )}
              </p>
            </FormItem>
          </Form>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      isAuthenticated: state.authentication.isAuthenticated,
      token: state.authentication.token
    });


    const LoginForm = Form.create({})(Login);
    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { loginWithGoogle, loginWithForm }
    )(LoginForm);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: when successfully login in and getting a token or isAuthenticated true the page should redirect to home

Comment: Your code looks ok, the way to do it is to redirect in the render. The only problem I see here is that `isAuthenticated` isn't updated since you're saving it to the state. What's the reason you're saving it? If you want to save it, then update the state in `componentDidUpdate`, if there's no need, just reference the updated `isAuthenticated` from the props.

Comment: solved thank you brother